# Get Windows service dependencies using C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi

I can use PowerShell to do this fairly easily, but I am looking for a C# way to do this. With PS, I can use Get-Service to iterate over the collection and check collections in there called DependentServices and RequiredServices to get the list of the dependent and required services for a given service.

I've looked into the WMI model using the query "Select * from Win32_Service", but this returns a collection of [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects that does not seem to have the collections I am interested in. I feel like I am missing something here. I have looked around and tried various searches, but I've not turned up a C#-centric way of doing this.

I want to query a given service and get back the collections mentioned above (DependentServices and RequiredServices). Sorry if I missed the obvious, but I really have not been able to find relevant topics.

Comment: I found an odd behavior with a specific windows service in all this that I felt is worth sharing. The NetMsmqActivator service on my laptop (Disabled) shows no service dependencies in the services.msc interface. However, when using the ServiceController class to get the ServicesDependedOn collection, you get 2 items in that collection which, when you try to access properties on them throws an InvalidOperationException. Very odd, but worth mentioning. I don't know what the fix would be, so, for now, I am eating the exception.

Comment: Another interesting, and perhaps frustrating anomaly I have found is in lenovo's "ThinkVantage System Update" package on my laptop. This installation seems to be corrupt and causes issues when iterating over the collection. For instance, I did not know you could have an installation succeed without the Manufacturer property being set for the MSI, but ThinkVantage System Update seems to have done just that. Still fleshing this out, but I have removed and re-installed the TV System Update package with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class:

```
StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (var svc in System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices())
{
    sb.AppendLine("============================");
    sb.AppendLine(svc.DisplayName);
    foreach (var dep in svc.DependentServices)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("\t{0}", dep.DisplayName);
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Win32_DependentService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class and the  `Associators of` sentence to retrieve the dependent services.

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                ManagementScope Scope;                   
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("Associators of {Win32_Service.Name='NetMan'} Where AssocClass=Win32_DependentService ResultClass=Win32_Service");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Name",WmiObject["Name"]);// String

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.dependentservices.aspx

```
ServiceController sc =  new ServiceController("Event Log");
         ServiceController[] scServices = sc.DependentServices;

         // Display the list of services dependent on the Event Log service.
         if (scServices.Length == 0)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no services dependent on {0}", 
                               sc.ServiceName);
         }
         else 
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Services dependent on {0}:",
                               sc.ServiceName);

            foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(" {0}", scTemp.DisplayName);
            }
         }
```